# Start EC2 nodes from Autoscaling group with Iam role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I configuring an Autoscaling group in CloudFormation and I'm trying to start all the ec2 nodes with an IAM role attached to them (one that can allow access to s3 for example).

I know that in CloudFormation there is the `ServiceLinkedRoleARN` key. According to the docs this key is using by default the AutoScalingServiceRolePolicy  role and it doesn't have S3 access. I can't create a Custom role  that contains both S3 role and the AutoScalingServiceRole role because I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot attach a Service Role Policy to a Customer Role.
```

So should I attach to the scaling group only a custom role of s3 ? What is the best practice way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration` there is a property called `IamInstanceProfile` that can be used exactly for that.

Please notice, in the role's page, there are 2 arns : `profile-role-arn` and `role-arn`. I first didn't notice that and used the role-arn. The right arn to use is the profile-arn.

Answer (score 0):

You specify the instance role for instances in your ASG in either `LaunchConfiguration` (LC) or `LaunchTemplate` (LT):

- LC: [IamInstanceProfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#cfn-as-launchconfig-iaminstanceprofile):

  > Provides the name or the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the instance profile associated with the IAM role for the instance. The instance profile contains the IAM role.
- LT: [IamInstanceProfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-launchtemplate-launchtemplatedata.html#cfn-ec2-launchtemplate-launchtemplatedata-iaminstanceprofile)

  > The IAM instance profile.